# How to implement GMSK model by Thierry Turletti

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, gmsk

I'm kind of new to signal processing and trying to implement a GMSK modulator using GMSK in a nutshell by Thierry Turletti to modulate a bunch of binary data and send them over RF antennas. I'm very confused about what is happening in this model.
[image]

1. How do you integrate NRZ data? integrating 1 is x+c and -1 would be -x+c. is this what it really asking to do?
2. Assuming this picture below is how a gaussian filter is used, Are we supposed to use the 2-D filter?

[image]

3. I've seen couple of different implementations of this method but no one uses any trigonometric functions. everyone just calculates the convolution of data coming out of the gaussian filter and ends it right there. what are the sin and cos doing in here? are they the carrier signal?
4. How is I and Q separated in here. are the data bits fed in parallel similar to QPSK?

Comment: So, feedback upfront: that block diagram isn't very high-quality in terms of symbol placement and formulas, it looks copied together from old sources, which might indicate the source you're reading might not be the best one (or very old). Then: Why do you start with a NRZ signal? That's terminology of the 1970s/1980s, maybe early 1990s, to be honest. This is not how you build a GMSK modulator in hardware or software in the last 20 years! Is it really a NRZ signal that you start with, or do you actually have *bits*?

Comment: and where would you put the second dimension of a 2D filter? This seems to make no sense to me, where does the $y$ in your formula come from?

Comment: "everyone ends right after the Gaussian filter": yes, because everyone just deals with *complex baseband*, a concept that you should really be familiar with before building a GMSK transceiver!

Comment: (plus, unless there's a very peculiar meaning of "Integrator", I'd argue this flow chart is plain wrong; a constant +1 NRZ signal input would lead to anything but GMSK modulation...)

Comment: I have about 7500 bytes of binary data to send using QPSK and GMSK methods. data needs to be converted to NRZ-L format. QPSK method was pretty straight forward but I'm very confused about how to implement a noncoherent GMSK mod/demod. I'm using Matlab for this purpose but not allowed to use comm toolbox. I've gone through tons of websites but they mostly seem to copy this implementation which you mentioned it was wrong. Any suggestions for a good and through resource on this?

Comment: well, you already know QPSK; so learn about (start with wikipedia) minimum-shift keying and how it relates to O-QPSK. You can then convert your QPSK transmitter to an OQPSK transmitter. Then it's just adding a (1d) gaussian filter.